# Does the Radeon 5500-XT support macOS Metal?

Tags: graphics-cards, macos

I want to purchase an AMD Radeon 5500 XT to improve FCPX renders and faster Blender renders.

I assume this would be a eGPU. Does macOS support this video card?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Reddit and Geekbench, Yes

Sources: https://www.reddit.com/r/eGPU/comments/igul8w/macos_10156_and_gigabyte_radeon_rx_5500_xt_oc_8g/

https://browser.geekbench.com/metal-benchmarks

Comment: Many of the cards on the Geekbench list are not Metal2 capable. I don't know *precisely* which, but even the official Apple HD 5700 definitely isn't, & was a halting point for many who could otherwise have upgraded to Mojave when it first came out.